# Including libcurl in Android App with Native Functions

Tags: android-ndk, libcurl, android-permissions

I'm having a subtle problem using libcurl in some native routines that are called from an Android app.  When I try to do a get request, libcurl says "Couldn't resolve host name."

I'm following the standard procedure of putting some c++ code in a jni folder with an Android.mk file. In the Android.mk, I used the $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) command to creates a shared library I can use with my Java Android App. The Android app starts up, loads the shared library, and calls some functions, which end up calling libcurl functions.

I included libcurl by including libcurl.a in my shared library, along with libssl.a, libcrypto.a, and libcares.a. The procedure is to create a stanza for each in the Android.mk ending in include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY).

Each of these static libraries were built for android using the ndk's arm-androideabi-linux cross compiler. I added the last one, libcares, more recently to try to solve the "Couldn't resolve host name" error, and rebuilt curl with libcares support.

Now here's the weird part: to try to figure out what was going on, I wrote a small main(){ } test app and linked it with these same static libraries via a single big gcc command, and ran it on my phone as a native arm executable. It works fine! I am able to load my own self-signed certificate into libcurl and do a get request over https to my server's internet url, and it works great. 
I have also gone through the whole process of building things in the x86_64 architecture and got it working there too.

What I can't figure out is why I'm still getting "Cannot Resolve Host" in my android app.

Curl info:

```
curl version:     7.48.0
Host setup:       arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
Install prefix:   /home/cworth/src/libcurl-android_built-w-23/local
Compiler:         arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
zlib support:     enabled
GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
TLS-SRP support:  enabled
resolver:         c-ares
IPv6 support:     enabled
Unix sockets support: enabled
IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes
Built-in manual:  enabled
--libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
ca cert bundle:   no
ca cert path:     no
ca fallback:      no
LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
RTSP support:     enabled
RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

SONAME bump:     yes - WARNING: this library will be built with the SONAME
                 number bumped due to (a detected) ABI breakage.
                 See lib/README.curl_off_t for details on this.
```

Android.mk

```
CURLINC = ../../libcurl-android_built-w-23/local/include
CURLLIB = ../../libcurl-android_built-w-23/local/lib
LOCAL_PATH := .

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE = crypto
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CURLINC)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CURLLIB)/libcrypto.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE = ssl
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CURLINC)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CURLLIB)/libssl.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE = cares
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CURLINC)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CURLLIB)/libcares.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE = curl
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CURLINC)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CURLLIB)/libcurl.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mynativelibrary
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pthread -Ijni
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions rtti
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += {my source files.cpp}
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  curl cares ssl crypto
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -landroid -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public native String talkToServer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!runOnce) {
            runOnce = true;
            Thread.currentThread().setName("Main");
            System.loadLibrary("mynativelibrary");
        }            
....
```

Logcat:

```
04-08 02:33:17.023 28328-28506/com.domain.me D/notes: 2016-04-08'T'02:33:17'Z': GET https://example.com:22222/api/notes.json
04-08 02:33:17.023 28328-28506/com.domain.me D/notes: 2016-04-08'T'02:33:17'Z': GET result: Couldn't resolve host name
```

Answer (score 0):

not a curl problem at all. I hadn't transferred the Android permissions from an older version of the app. However, ended up solving a bunch of curl build issues (with ssl and resolver support) I would have had anyway along the way.

I don't know if this is useful question to leave up on SO or not.

Comment: So you're saying that you have a working curl implementation for Android? Which version of Android? I haven't found any that work with PIE.

Comment: It's Marshmallow and curl-7.48.0. Just tested out the binary curl that got built when I built curl, but it expects shared libs that aren't on my phone. Don't want to jump through the hoops, but you could change the last step of the build and link everything statically. It would work, just like it works when I link libcurl statically with my java/native app. (As you say, I had to add LDFLAGS=-fPIE -pie and --with-pic for newer Android). Update: looks like Cyanogenmod 13 also comes with a binary curl that works (at least for the lg g3)